# MySQL replication username

Tags: replication, mysql-5.5, limits

What is the difference in using these two approaches when setting master-slave replication:

1. Setting the binlog-do-db option on the master to choose which DBs are going to be replicated;
2. Creating a replication user on master and granting the access to only one DB.

Do these two options get the same results or no?

I understand that without binlog-do-db option, master server will copy all the data to the binlog, however I'm not sure whether the slave server will copy all of them to the relaylog or that depends on the user setup for the replication?

The idea behind all this is to setup a bit more complicated chained replication setup and I'm trying to understand more about binlogs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions granted to the replication user do not affects databases/tables he can replicate. The only significant grant is `REPLICATION SLAVE` that allows to read the master binlog whatever was written to it.

You can restrict databases to be replicated on the master side with `binlog_do_db` or `binlog_ignore_db` directive, but you can't restrict tables the same way. All events from the master's binlog will be replicated by each slave connected so you can't create a different users for different sets of databases. Each slave can filter out some databases or tables from the common binlog by `replicate_do_db`, `replicate_do_table`, `replicate_ignore_db` and `replicate_ignore_table` directives.